# Python 3 replacement for ftputil?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftputil

I'm looking for an alternative to the [ftputil](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac) library. Should work with python 3 and would be nice if its in the Archlinux repos.

Is there any?

Comment: Have you asked the author? He might just not have ported it to Python 3 because nobody asked him yet. Or you can do it. Porting is fun! http://python3porting.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ftputil` for Python 3 has been released. Here is the official page where to download it: http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Download

Answer (score 1):

Never considered using the built-in [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ftplib.html)?

Comment: Of course i did, but ftputil is much more comfortable when doing up- and downloads and iterating through directory trees.